# Loopback ACL are not working after deploying to Heroku

Tags: heroku, loopbackjs

I have a fully functioning Loopback application on localhost, Relations, ACLs, Access management... everything works like a charm.

Deployed my application to Heroku, suddenly ACLs are no longer functional.

Here is an example of a model's ACL:

```
"acls": [
{
  "accessType": "*",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$everyone",
  "permission": "DENY"
},
```

yet when I write the endpoint url

```
...herokuapp.com/api/<modelname>
```

I get all the informations

PS: changing datasource to localhost and querying

```
localhost:3000/api/<modelname>
```

won't allow any information unless logged in as an authorized User.

**EDIT:** the problem actually concerns only the predefined loopback models, as the relations added between the User model and others were erased (User model went back to its default build I am guessing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When editing the core models of the framework, I forgot to mark down the changes and apply them again after deploying. In deployment, the framework copies the core models from the main library and not the files I edited